Can I use a 20A toggle switch to change between batteries and a 30A campground outlet?
I'm building an RV from a bread truck. I'm using a 120v fridge, 120v portable AC, and a 120v TV. I'm running solar to a deep cycle battery which has a 2000/4000 watt sine wave inverter. I want to run an extension cord between the RV and the campground hookup which is 30 amps, but when not in a campground I want to be able to run the fridge and AC thru the deep cycle battery using a toggle that is 20 amps to switch between campgrounds and and battery. Is this right or not?

Have you looked at made-for-purpose RV automatic transfer switches?

"a deep cycle battery " how did you size this battery? will it run the fridge and a/c for 5 minutes or 5 hours or 5 days?

No it's not right to use a toggle switch to select between campground ("shore power") and battery ("inverter/generator power"). This is because disconnecting the neutral too will be good and switching a ground-neutral bond is very important.
The simplest transfer switch is a plug and cord. Plug all your things in the RV into an outlet strip. Plug the outlet strip to the inverter when you want to run on battery, or plug it to the extension cord when you want to run on campground/shore power.
